# I am trying to load data infile in mysql from a .csv

Tags: mysql, windows, csv

I am trying to **load data infile** in mysql from a .csv file and one of the columns has a link to a folder on my PC. I have worked out that to be able to make Mysql read the c:\ I need to use 2 forward slashes c:\ and put a , at the end of the text. However it is now placing a **"** at the beginning of the text and will only load one line of the .csv. Does anyone have any tips that I can use to fix this one

Comment: You need to try backticks instead of double quotes eg. 'value'

Comment: Do you have the table structure,sample lines of csv file and your command?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a CSV-file example -

```
1,c:\\
2,c:\\dir
3,c:\\new dir
```

It is a table to import data -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  path varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And it is our LOAD DATA query -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.txt' INTO TABLE table1
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Output -

```
SELECT *  FROM table1;
1   c:\
2   c:\dir
3   c:\new dir
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for amswering this
Here is the format of the .CSV file

```
\N  1   Copper Red Dish 001 Shallow Copper Red dish f   450 50cm diame  c:\\catalog\\bcpot020.jpg,
\N  1   Copper Red Bottle 001   Copper Red bottle form.     550 60cm tall   c:\\catalog\\bcpot003.jpg,
\N  10  Chun bowl 001   Blue Chun bowl with tea s   350 20 cm diam  c:\\catalog\\bcpot006.jpg,
\N  2   Moonscape bowl 001  High Calcium bowl with wh   320 40cm diame  c:\\catalog\\bcpot009.jpg,
\N  3   Crystalline bowl 001    Blue Green Crystalline gl   250 20 cm diam  c:\\catalog\\bcpot013_thumb.jpg,
```

This is the SQL file to run this into MYSQL

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
USE BazzaarCeramics_db;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Data\\Product.csv'
    INTO TABLE Product
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY 'r\N'
     (`ProductID`,`ProductGlazeTypeCode`,`ProductTitle`,`ProductDescription`,`ProductPrice`,`ProductSize`,`ProductRelativePath`);
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

And this is what is returned when I run it.

```
21  1   Copper Red Dish 001 Shallow Copper Red dish f   450.00  50cm diame  "c:\catalog\bcpot020.jpg
```

Note the " at the beginning of the address.
I get this if I place a comma , at the end of the address. If I do not do the comma it places an N at the end of the address.

Hope this helps

Comment: As I see, line separator is ',' + new line (\n or \r\n). Field separators are different - random white spaces. It is not a CSV-file.